# VM options in project properties in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, out-of-memory, size, heap-memory

I got a problem with the java heap space while using servlets in netbeans5.0 and got a solution to resolve it too,they asked to change the VM options of run category in the project properties.But,i couldnt find such option in my properties.Please do tell me what to do with this error. This is the picture of my project properties.

[alt text http://img390.imageshack.us/img390/4116/28257416.png](http://img390.imageshack.us/img390/4116/28257416.png)

Comment: Could you attach the image please?

Comment: And could you tell us what sort of project it is (when you created the project in NetBeans, what sort of project was it?)

Answer (score 2):

It it's netbeans that is short of memory then edit netbeans\etc\netbeans.conf and add/edit to the property netbeans_ default_options something like:

```
-J-Xms128m -J-Xmx128m -J-XX:PermSize=64m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

If it's your servlet container (tomcat) that is short of memory after many redeployments then right click on tomcat > properties > platform > vm options:

```
-Xms128m -Xmx128m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Feel free to experiment with the numbers. The above are semi-random.